# How to access leftover text in ng-tags-input

Tags: ng-tags-input

Is the left over text in input accessible programatically? If so, how?

I only allow tags from autocomplete (to use as search filters), and want to use the left over text as additional keywords, meaning I want to know if it's bound to anything so I can pass it to a search function.

Thanks for the help

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"want to use the leftover text as additional keywords"*?

Comment: Just edited, i want to know iff the leftover text is bound to anything ao that i can pass it to a search function. Does that make sense?

Comment: You mean a search function other than the one used to populate the autocomplete list?

Comment: Yes. A search function to filter results elsewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not directly possible, but you can hack into the directive and make it work by using a helper directive:

```
app.directive('bindInternalInputTo', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    var property = attrs.bindInternalInputTo,
        input = element.find('input'),
        inputScope = input.scope();

    inputScope.$watch('newTag.text', function(value) {
      scope[property] = value;
    });
  };
});
```

Now you can bind some variable in the outer scope to the inner input by doing the following:

```
<tags-input ng-model="tags" bind-internal-input-to="variable"></tags-input>
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z2yq5Sj18dTGNGJRmoLw?p=preview)

Please note that this solution isn't guaranteed to work with future versions of ngTagsInput since it relies on internal implementation details.

Comment: thank you very much! im new to angular and have learned TONS by looking at the code in this projects and seeing how you do things the angular way.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me to access the internal tag validation property 'newTag.invalid' so I could expose for external validation reporting.

Comment: As Michael stated, this solution was limited to the version of the library it was written for. This plunker/solution no longer function as designed.